# The Logic of False Statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I"m wondering whether it's valid to carry logical operations across false statements, same as as you would across true statements.

Compare:

$$\begin{alignat*}{3} 
& \ 1 < 2 \\
\Rightarrow & \ 1 + 1 < 2 + 1 \\
\Rightarrow & \ \frac{1}{3} <  \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{alignat*}$$

With:

$$\begin{alignat*}{3} 
& \ 2 < 1 &&\hspace{2cm} \text{is false} \\
\Rightarrow & \ 2 + 1 < 1 + 1 &&\hspace{2cm} \text{is false} \\
\Rightarrow & \ \frac{1}{2} < \frac {1}{3} &&\hspace{2cm} \text{is false} \\
\end{alignat*}$$

Comment: Not clear... From $1 < 2$ you add $1$ to both to get correctly $2 < 3$. Then how you derive ; $\dfrac 1 2 < 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$(2<1) → (3<2)$  is True, because the antecedent is False (see [Material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)).

Logical operations are carried on statements, either true or false.

But [valid logical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) license the truth of the *conclusion* only when applied to true *premises*.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you're asking, in essence,

> If I have two claims $A$ and $B$ and I have proved $A\Rightarrow B$, would that also work for proving $\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B$?

No, you can't do that. For an example where it goes wrong, you can reason
$$ x > 2 \implies x^2 > 4 $$
but there are examples of $x$ where $x>2$ is false yet $x^2>4$ is true -- e.g. this is the case for $x=-3$.

---

The conclusion is your particular example is indeed true, but you need to justify it differently. One option is to simply write "$x\ge y$" instead of "$x < y$ is false"; it turns out that each of your rewritings is still true with a different inequality sign.

Another option is to note that each of the $\Rightarrow$ in your original reasoning could actually be $\Leftrightarrow$ -- and it *does* generally hold that if you have proved $A\Leftrightarrow B$, then you'll also know $\neg A\Leftrightarrow\neg B$.

Answer (score 0):

Logic doesn’t care about what is actually true; it just concerns itself with what can be inferred from what. Therefore, logic can be applied just as well to true statements as false statements.

Thus, for example, if you have as an axiom that whenever $x <y$ then $x+1<y+1$, then you can use that to infer $3<2$ from $2<1$ just as much as you can infer that $2<3$ from $1<2$

Comment: Modus ponens only works when the antecedent is true and the conditional is true.  If the antecedent is false,and the conditional is true, it isn't valid to infer that the consequent is false.

Comment: I wasn’t saying that since the antecedent is false then the consequent is false... i was just showing a case where you can make a valid inference on false statements, which I thought the question was about ... but maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

No.

2 < 1 is false.  Therefore, "2 < 1 implies that (2 + 1) < (1 + 1)" is a true statement, because F => T and F => F are both true in classical logic.  However, by the same reasoning, we can't infer 2 < 1 as false, and  "2 < 1 implies that (2 + 1) < (1 + 1)" as true, that (2 + 1) < (1 + 1) is false, since  (2 + 1) < (1 + 1) could be true.